# How to determine invalid inputs in c

Tags: c, input, floating-point, invalid-characters

I want to take an float input but if the user gives a character input it will show invalid input, I didn't found a specific answer on the net. 
How is it done?

Comment: A good start would be to enter `scanf` on your favorite search-engine (aka Google).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code fragment:

```
int num;
float val;

num = scanf("%f", &val);
if(num != 1)
{
    printf("You didn't enter a float!\n");
}
```

`scanf` returns the number of items that it successfully scans.  In your case, you're trying to scan one item, a `float`.  If the user doesn't enter a `float`, `scanf` will return `0`.

Note: If `scanf` fails, whatever garbage data the user entered will still be in the `stdin` stream.  You'll have to manually flush it.  Here's one such way:

```
while(((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
    continue;
```

Warning: Don't use `fflush` on `stdin`.

**Edit**

Even if `scanf` doesn't fail, you may still have garbage in the `stdin` buffer.  For example, if the user enters:

> 123xyz

`123` will be assigned to the float, and everything after `x` will stay in the `stdin` stream.

Comment: input like 123xyz is valid?

Comment: @SHR `123` is valid, but `xyz` is invalid and remains in the `stdin` stream. You'll need to manually flush this because it may accidentally be used in another function call that gets its data from `stdin`.

Comment: why fflush on stdin would create a problem?

Comment: @Jimut `fflush` is meant for output streams only (e.g. `stdout`).

Comment: Minor: `while(getchar() != '\n')` --> infinite loop on `EOF`.

Answer (score 2):

While `scanf` is safe to parse a double, many compilers have deprecated its use (for good reason) becuase it is unsafe when parsing a string.  Additionally, should the parse fail, you will be left with the remains in the input buffer and you will have to flush it yourself.

For these reasons, prefer a function like `fgets`, which checks the length of its supplied buffer, and then a function like `strtod` or `sscanf` to make the conversion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[64];

    /* read */
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        /* convert */
        char *err;
        double d = strtod(buf, &err);
        if (*err) {
            puts("entry invalid");
        } else {
            printf("you entered %lf", d);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: input like 123xyz is valid?

Comment: Everyone is suggesting `scanf` because `scanf` is not “inherently” unsafe to parse a `double`.

Comment: Well, okay, 50% of `scanf`-suggesting answers are suggesting `scanf` because `scanf` is not inherently unsafe.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Yeah, fair enough re: parsing a number, but I still wouldn't use/teach it.  I removed that bit.

Comment: `if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { double d = strtod(buf, &err); if (*err) {` is a problem, but on the right track.  `fgets()` will most often get a string ending in `"\n\0"` and then `*err` will have the `'\n'` in it.  Maybe add `while (isspace(*err)) err++` before the `if()`?